# how to find the index of particular element in the array

Tags: swift

I have NSMutablearray.

```
 var answers1 = NSMutableArray ()
```

This is the array.

I have got the array.Now the array is as below.

```
("","","","sam","jeena")
```

This is the data.Now i need to check whether in the answer1 has the element "" and i need to get the index where the string as "".And also if index is get then show the alert.

Example:-here "" -is available in index of 0,1,2 .So iterate the NSMutablearray Then first show alert as :-please select the data from index0.

Actually here i have one tableview(grouped).So for each section i have selected one answer.Like that each answer is appending in the Array.

So i need to check in the answer array,did i have selected one cell from each section.If not then display as:-

```
   print("Please select item at",(section))

                    let questionModel = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: section)
                    print(questionModel.question)

                    let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Please Select any option from question", message:(questionModel.question), preferredStyle: .alert)
                    // Create the actions
                    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                        UIAlertAction in
                        NSLog("OK Pressed")
                        //   self.viewDidLoad()
                        //

                    }
                    controller.addAction(okAction)
                    //  controller.addAction(cancel)

                    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


          How to do?
```

Comment: how to find the index which contain the element "" in the array

Answer (score 2):

Rather than the items `filter` the indices

```
let array = ["","","","edsdfg","fhjuyj","dfhjg"] 
let emptyIndices = array.indices.filter{ array[$0].isEmpty } // [0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: But here showing an error as value of NSMutableArray has no member indices how to solve?

Comment: my array is NSMutablearray

Comment: Don’t use `NSMutableArray` in Swift at all. Use native array (and dictionary).

Comment: i have update my question .please check .i need according

Comment: Declare the variable `var answers1 = [String]()`

Comment: i have done in nsmutablearray how to check according

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function, something like this to find the indices.

```
func allIndices(ofArray: [String], forElement: String) -> [Int] {
    var indices = [Int]()
    for (index, element) in str.enumerated() {
        if element == forElement {
            indices.append(index)
        }
    }
    return indices
}
```

And you can call it as

```
let result = allIndices(ofArray: stringArray, forElement: "")
```

Comment: i have update my question .please check .i need according

Comment: how to do? i need to do this in button action....